# no puedo obtener el valor un campo de texto-python

Tags: python, tkinter, get

quiero obtener el valor de un campo de texto con el método get() pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

la variable que quiero obtener la quiero mostrar por un print en el método mostrar, pero no puedo porque no me obtiene el valor de la variable.
He visto videos en los que utilizan el `get()` y les funciona pero a mi no me funciona :(

código:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class Login:
    def __init__(self,raiz1):
        self.ventana = raiz1  

        self.ventana.config(width=450,height=270)      
        self.ventana.title("Login user")


        #label user y campo de texto
        self.user = Label(self.ventana, text="Usuario: ",bg="black",fg = "white",font=("Arial",13)).place(x=50,y=40)

        self.userIn =Entry(self.ventana,bg="black",fg="white",font=("Arial",13)).place(x=50,y=80)



        #label password y campo de texto
        self.password = Label(self.ventana, text="contraseña: ",bg = "black",fg = "white",font=("Arial",13)).place(x=50,y=130)

        self.passIn = Entry(self.ventana,show="*",text="",bg="black",fg="white",font=("Arial",13)).place(x=50,y=170)


        #crear boton
        self.login = Button(self.ventana,text="Loguear",bg="black",fg="white",font=("Arial",16),command= self.mostrar).place(x=50,y=220)


    def mostrar(self):
        print(self.userIn.get())#aqui es mi problema

raiz1 = Tk()

aplicacion1 = Login(raiz1)

raiz1.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Te falta asociar una variable en `Entry()` del tipo `StringVar()` con el parámetro `textvariable` para que sea ésta la que almacene la información:

```
self.userText = StringVar()
self.userIn =Entry(self.ventana, textvariable=self.userText, bg="black", fg="white", font=("Arial",13)).place(x=50, y=80)
```

y así poder mostrarla haciendo:

```
print(self.userText.get())
```

porque `Entry().place()` retorna `None`.

Answer (score 1):

No funcioa porque self.userIn no es un widget Entry, es None como el error claramente indica. Ésto se debe a que instanciaa el widget así:

```
self.userIn =Entry(self.ventana,...)).place(x=50,y=80)
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

a `self.userIn` no se le asigna la referencia al objeto `Entry` creado, se le asigna la salida de su método place, que es `None`. El atributo ahora no sirve absolutamente para nada.

- Si vas a necesitar referenciar al objeto en alguna momento, realiza la llamada a `place`/`grid`/`pack` de forma separada a la instanciación:

  ```
  self.userIn =Entry(self.ventana,...))
  self.userIn.place(x=50,y=80)
  ```
- Si no necesitas referencia nunca al objeto no crees una variable o método asociado al mismo:

  ```
  Entry(self.ventana,...)).place(x=50,y=80)
  ```

Por otro lado, no es un error, pero el uso de satart/wildcard para importar es una mala práctica, te recomiendo evitarlo. La forma generalmente aceptada por convención de importar tkinter es mediante `import tkinter as tk`.

Te dejo el código cumpliendo además con las [convenciones de estilo definidas en PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

```
import tkinter as tk


class Login:
    def __init__(self, raiz):
        self.ventana = raiz

        self.ventana.config(width=450, height=270)
        self.ventana.title("Login user")

        # Label user y campo de texto
        tk.Label(
            self.ventana, text="Usuario: ", bg="black",
            fg="white", font=("Arial", 13)
            ).place(x=50, y=40)

        self.user_in = tk.Entry(
            self.ventana, bg="black", fg="white", font=("Arial", 13)
            )
        self.user_in.place(x=50, y=80)

        # Label password y campo de texto
        tk.Label(
            self.ventana, text="contraseña: ", bg="black",
            fg="white", font=("Arial", 13)
            ).place(x=50, y=130)

        self.pass_in = tk.Entry(
            self.ventana, show="*", text="", bg="black",
            fg="white", font=("Arial", 13)
            )
        self.pass_in.place(x=50, y=170)

        # Crear boton
        tk.Button(
            self.ventana, text="Loguear", bg="black",
            fg="white", font=("Arial", 16), command=self.mostrar
            ).place(x=50, y=220)

    def mostrar(self):
        print(self.user_in.get())
        print(self.pass_in.get())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    raiz = tk.Tk()
    aplicacion = Login(raiz)
    raiz.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías optimizar tu código de esta manera

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class Login:
    def __init__(self,raiz1):
        self.ventana = raiz1  

        self.ventana.config(width=450,height=270)      
        self.ventana.title("Login user")


        #label user y campo de texto
        self.user = Label(self.ventana, text="Usuario: ",bg="black",fg = "white",font=("Arial",13))
        self.user.place(x=50,y=40)

        self.userText = StringVar()
        self.userIn =Entry(self.ventana, textvariable=self.userText, bg="black", fg="white", font=("Arial",13))
        self.userIn.place(x=50,y=80)



        #label password y campo de texto
        self.password = Label(self.ventana, text="contraseña: ",bg = "black",fg = "white",font=("Arial",13))
        self.password.place(x=50,y=130)

        self.passIn = Entry(self.ventana,show="*",text="",bg="black",fg="white",font=("Arial",13))
        self.passIn.place(x=50,y=170)


        #crear boton
        self.login = Button(self.ventana,text="Loguear",bg="black",fg="white",font=("Arial",16),command= self.mostrar)
        self.login.place(x=50,y=220)


    def mostrar(self):
        print(self.userText.get())

raiz1 = Tk()

aplicacion1 = Login(raiz1)

raiz1.mainloop()
```

## y así quedaría

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]